# Meaning of “ne s'accrocher que pour lire”

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I can't understand what *s'accrocher* means in this phrase. The whole phrase appears to be translated into English, "Those letters she receives from her hometown are the only things keeping her going." But I don't know with which part *s'accrocher* has any connection in this phrase.

> Elle ne s'accroche que pour lire les lettres qu'elle reçoit de sa ville natale.

Answer (score 3):

More context might help but *s'accrocher* is used figuratively here and indeed means something like "to keep going", "to hang" or "to cling" (thanks to aCOSwt and Laurent S. for the suggestions).

*S'accrocher* means "to refrain to give up, to keep going despite the difficulties".

Comment: More *to cling* than just to *keep going* ?

Comment: What is meant could implicitly be: "Elle ne s'accroche (à la vie) que pour..."

Comment: S'accrocher is used I think like "hang" is used in the Famous "[Hang in there, Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_in_there,_Baby)"

Answer (score 3):

“S'accrocher” is literally similar to “hold on”, meaning “endure in difficult circumstances”, but its connotations are sometimes close to “keep going”. This sentence is difficult to translate and “keep going” just fits better the chosen English phrasing. Also note that in the French phrasing, reading the letters has more accurately become the only motive/purpose that keeps her going.